# Maven Jaxb plugin error-Required class missing

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, pom.xml

I am using maven 3.1.0.

I am getting error while trying to build through cmd.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb1.maven2:maven-jaxb1-plugin:1.0-rc9:generate (default) on project Myproject: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb1.maven2:maven-jaxb1-plugin:1.0-rc9:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb1.maven2:maven-jaxb1-plugin:1.0-rc9:generate: com/sun/msv/grammar/Grammar
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb1.maven2:maven-jaxb1-plugin:1.0-rc9
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb1/maven2/maven-jaxb1-plugin/1.0-rc9/maven-jaxb1-plugin-1.0-rc9.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/1.0.6/jaxb-xjc-1.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/1.0.6/jaxb-impl-1.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/1.0/jaxb-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/javax/xml/parsers/jaxp-api/1.4/jaxp-api-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/parsers/jaxp-ri/1.4/jaxp-ri-1.4.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: com.sun.msv.grammar.Grammar
```

**I have called maven through command line.**

My POM.xml looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb1.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb1-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-rc9</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
               <goal> generate  </goal>
            </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
<configuration>
<generatePackage>jaxb1/package</generatePackage>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show the full error output instead of only excerpts? How have you called maven? On Command line or from within Eclipse / IDE ?

Comment: jaxb1 is ancient - there's no reason to use that ny more.

Comment: Pasted full error output

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of this plugin, wrote it ages ago.

As @skaffman said, JAXB 1 is ancient, so the `maven-jaxb1-plugin` is not actively supported at the moment. Please use the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) instead.

If there are specific reasons for you to be forced to use `maven-jaxb1-plugin`, you'll probably have to fix it yourself. I can move the code to the GitHub and will accept pull requests. This is the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: Compared old  jaxb-impl and  jaxb-libs pom files, it seems dependencies are missing in newly generated pom file.
jaxb-impl-1.0.6 pom file dependencies jaxb-api and jaxb-libs are missing  jaxb-libs-1.0.6 pom file is missing dependency xsdlib.

Included the missing dependencies in my project pom file. But still same issue.Any idea?